# (Ogre3d/PhysX/C++) - how to do draw debug visualization

Tags: c++, ogre3d, physx

Can you help me. I can not understand how to draw PhysX debug visualization in Ogre3D, together with normal objects.

I have the code for OpenGL, but i can not convert it to Ogre3d:

```
void RenderData(const PxRenderBuffer & data)
{
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    //----------Render Points------------------
    unsigned int NbPoints = data.getNbPoints();
    if(NbPoints)
    {
        float* pVertList = new float[NbPoints*3];
        float* pColorList = new float[NbPoints*4];
        int vertIndex = 0;
        int colorIndex = 0;
        const PxDebugPoint* Points = data.getPoints();
        while(NbPoints--)
        {
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Points->pos.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Points->pos.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Points->pos.z;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Points->color>>16)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Points->color>>8)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)(Points->color&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = 1.0f;
            Points++;
        }

        RenderBuffer(pVertList, pColorList, GL_POINTS, data.getNbPoints());

        delete[] pVertList;
        delete[] pColorList;
    }


    //----------Render Lines------------------
    unsigned int NbLines = data.getNbLines();
    if(NbLines)
    {
        float* pVertList = new float[NbLines*3*2];
        float* pColorList = new float[NbLines*4*2];
        int vertIndex = 0;
        int colorIndex = 0;
        const PxDebugLine* Lines = data.getLines();
        while(NbLines--)
        {
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos0.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos0.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos0.z;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Lines->color0>>16)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Lines->color0>>8)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)(Lines->color0&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = 1.0f;

            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos1.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos1.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Lines->pos1.z;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Lines->color0>>16)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Lines->color0>>8)&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)(Lines->color0&0xff)/255.0f;
            pColorList[colorIndex++] = 1.0f;

            Lines++;
        }

        RenderBuffer(pVertList, pColorList, GL_LINES, data.getNbLines()*2);

        delete[] pVertList;
        delete[] pColorList;
    }


    //----------Render Triangles------------------
    unsigned int NbTris = data.getNbTriangles();
    if(NbTris)
    {
        float* pVertList = new float[NbTris*3*3];
        float* pColorList = new float[NbTris*4*3];
        int vertIndex = 0;
        int colorIndex = 0;
        const PxDebugTriangle* Triangles = data.getTriangles();
        while(NbTris--)
        {
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos0.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos0.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos0.z;

            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos1.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos1.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos1.z;

            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos2.x;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos2.y;
            pVertList[vertIndex++] = Triangles->pos2.z;

            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Triangles->color0>>16)&0xff)/255.0f;
                pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)((Triangles->color0>>8)&0xff)/255.0f;
                pColorList[colorIndex++] = (float)(Triangles->color0&0xff)/255.0f;
                pColorList[colorIndex++] = 1.0f;
            }

            Triangles++;
        }

        RenderBuffer(pVertList, pColorList, GL_TRIANGLES, data.getNbTriangles()*3);

        delete[] pVertList;
        delete[] pColorList;
    }
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
}

void RenderBuffer(float* pVertList, float* pColorList, int type, int num)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT, 0, pVertList);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, pColorList);

    glDrawArrays(type, 0, num);

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Certainly, you may not use this code. I just want to draw PhysX debug visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how the Ogre3D PhysX wrapper called "*NxOgre*" (combined with Critter which is the actual bridge to Ogre3D) does things. A good starting point would be the [wiki tutorial page](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=BloodyMess%20Tutorial%203).

**A rough outline:**
PhsyX provides for each scene in each world a debug render data structure. That can be taken and formed into a data structure that can be used within Ogre3D to be rendered.

```
for (World::SceneIterator iterator = mWorld->getScenes(); iterator != iterator.end(); iterator++)
{
    const NxDebugRenderable* renderable = iterator->getScene()->getDebugRenderable();
    if (renderable == 0)
       continue;

    unsigned int nbLines = renderable->getNbLines();
    const NxDebugLine* lines = renderable->getLines();

    while(nbLines--)
    {
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p0.x);
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p0.y);
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p0.z);
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p1.x);
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p1.y);
       mMeshData->mLines.push_back(lines->p1.z);
       mMeshData->mColours.push_back(lines->color);
       mMeshData->mColours.push_back(lines->color);
       lines++;
    }

    mMeshData->mNbLines += renderable->getNbLines();
}
```

**Most relevant parts:**

- [VisualDebugger::draw()](https://github.com/betajaen/nxogre/blob/buggyswires/build/source/NxOgreVisualDebugger.cpp#L335) = collect data from PhysX and store in structure to be alter passed on to the Ogre3D renderer
- [Renderable::drawVisualDebugger()](https://github.com/betajaen/critter/blob/master/build/source/CritterRenderable.cpp#L201) = previously stored data is passed to the Ogre3D vertex buffer